# Metal Crash - CVMetalTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage

Tags: ios, metal

I'm running in to a problem with creating textures in 16 bits.
`bgra8Unorm` works fine, tho `rgba16Float` causes a crash.

> validateStrideTextureParameters, line 1452: error 'IOSurface texture: bytesPerRow (5120) must be greater or equal to (10240) bytes'
>   validateStrideTextureParameters:1452: failed assertion `IOSurface texture: bytesPerRow (5120) must be greater or equal to (10240) bytes'

anyone knows how to fix this?

Comment: Why do you need to use rgba16Float?

Comment: You need to multiply the row width * sizeof(uint16_t) when creating the texture.

Comment: I'm working with 16bit to work with colors below 0.0 and above 1.0

Answer (score 1):

This error means that your Core Video pixel format and your MTLTexture pixel format are not compatible with each other. If you want to create a texture from CVMetalTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage your pixel format has to be the same.

Answer (score 1):

When you setup your `AVCaptureSession` you can specify the pixel format so that it matches the Metal pixel format.

- Core Video Pixel Format -> Metal Pixel Format
- `kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA` -> `MTLPixelFormat.bgra8Unorm`
- `kCVPixelFormatType_64RGBAHalf` -> `MTLPixelFormat.rgba16Float`

Setting up the code this way will fix the specific `validateStrideTextureParameters` assert crash above with CVMetalTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage.

### But in practice, I could only get `.bgra8Unorm` to work.

When using `.rgba16Float` and `64RGBAHalf` The create texture function return value was `kCVReturnFirst` `-6660` "Placeholder to mark the beginning of the range of CVReturn codes."

### Syncing AVKit and MetalKit pixel formats

This combo of 32bit BGRA pixel formats works together.

AVKit Section

```swift
let videoOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
videoOutput.videoSettings = [
    kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as String: 
        Int(kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA) // core video pixel format
]
captureSession.addOutput(videoOutput)
```

MetalKit Section

```swift
CVMetalTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage(
            kCFAllocatorDefault,
            textureCache,
            imageBuffer,
            nil,
            .bgra8Unorm, // metal pixel format
            width,
            height,
            0, // plane index
            &metalTextureOut)
```